# Generate 3D surface plot from 2D coordinates

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, 3d, surface, bin

I have a large coordinates data set, and I want to visualize the distribution in 3D format.

I can do a bin plot in 2D like this: [image]
Notice how the colour indicates different number of points within each bin. However, how could I do this in a 3D format? I want to use both the height and colour to account for numbers.

Comment: This is pretty interesting. What software are you using?

Comment: I plotted this 2d graph use R, but I am to open to any other softwares/languages

Comment: Oh, I meant software as in how did you produce visualize the graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you use both height and color for number, this mean that all the red will be at the same height and all the blue, below at the same other height, am I right?

There is a quick way to do that with an open source software called "FiJi ImageJ".
You can download it here: https://imagej.net/Fiji/Downloads

Then you can export your image above to a 3D surface plot using a built in function from the menu: "Analyse" > "3D Surface plot"

This is what I obtained for example with an image of 2 gaussians:
[image]